# Generating a stream of all possible tuples from given streams using Scheme

Tags: recursion, stream, scheme, sicp, lazy-sequences

I am trying to write a procedure `stream-weighted-tuples` that takes a weight procedure and any number of streams, to generate a stream of tuples.
For instance,

```lisp
(stream-weighted-tuples
  (lambda (t) (+ (car t) (cadr t) (caddr t))
  integers
  integers
  integers)
```

should generate a stream of `(1 1 1) (1 1 2) (1 2 1) (2 1 1) (1 1 3) (1 2 2) (1 3 1) (2 1 2) (2 2 1) (3 1 1) (1 1 4) (1 2 3) ...`.

I was inspired by [exercise 3.70](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_thm_3.70) in SICP, which is about writing a procedure `weighted-pairs` that takes two streams and a weight procedure to generate a stream of pairs in the order according to weight.
So basically, this is a generalization of the `weighted-pairs` procedure to take more than two streams.

I wrote the following version:

```lisp
    (define (stream-weighted-tuples weight . streams)
      (cond ((null? streams)
             (error "No streams given -- STREM-WEIGHTED-TUPLES"))
            ((null? (cdr streams))
             (stream-map list (car streams)))
            (else
              (let ((s (car streams))
                    (rest (cdr streams)))
                (if (stream-null? s)
                    the-empty-stream  ; {} x S = {}
                    (stream-merge-weighted
                      weight
                      (stream-map (lambda (tuple)
                                    (cons (stream-car s) tuple))
                                  (apply stream-weighted-tuples
                                         (lambda (tuple)  ; partial weight
                                           (weight (cons (stream-car s)
                                                         tuple)))
                                         rest))
                      (apply stream-weighted-tuples
                             weight
                             (stream-cdr s)
                             rest)))))))
```

(which apparently doesn’t work).
The idea was to merge 1. the stream resulting from `cons`ing the **first element of the first stream** with each element of the (recursively constructed) stream that consists of **the tuples from the rest of the given streams**, and 2. the stream that consists of the tuples of **the `stream-cdr` of the first stream** and the rest of the given streams.

This doesn’t work because generating stream 2 won’t halt in the case of an infinite stream (due to the same reason `pairs` procedure from [exercise 3.68](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_thm_3.68) doesn’t work).

This is `stream-merge-weighted` I implemented:

```lisp
    (define (stream-merge-weighted weight s1 s2)
      (cond ((stream-null? s1) s2)
            ((stream-null? s2) s1)
            (else
              (let* ((s1car (stream-car s1))
                     (s2car (stream-car s2))
                     (s1car-weight (weight s1car))
                     (s2car-weight (weight s2car)))
                (cond ((<= s1car-weight s2car-weight)
                       (cons-stream
                         s1car
                         (stream-merge-weighted weight
                                                (stream-cdr s1)
                                                s2)))
                      ((> s1car-weight s2car-weight)
                       (cons-stream
                         s2car
                         (stream-merge-weighted weight
                                                s1
                                                (stream-cdr s2)))))))))
```

Is there a way to recursively construct this problem?

---

EDIT: What I meant by “tuple” in this question is actually a Scheme list that semantically represents a tuple.

For reference, I leave my implementation of stream primitives (which is identical to the ones in SICP):

```lisp
    (define-syntax cons-stream
      (syntax-rules ()
        ((_ a b)
         (cons a (delay b)))))

    (define (stream-car stream)
      (car stream))
    (define (stream-cdr stream)
      (force (cdr stream)))

    (define (stream-null? stream)
      (null? stream))
    (define the-empty-stream '())

    (define (stream-map proc s)
      (if (stream-null? s)
          the-empty-stream
          (cons-stream
            (proc (stream-car s))
            (stream-map proc (stream-cdr s)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using a recursion structure similar to that of [the `pairs` procedure shown in SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#call_footnote_Temp_478).

The following `stream-weighted-tuples` works with recursively constructed stream of tuples of the `cdr` of streams (`rest-tuples`), and then uses the same recursion strategy to “pair” (unlike the original `pair` procedure, the other stream is already a stream of tuples) it with the `car` of streams (`combine-with-rest`).

```lisp
    (define (stream-weighted-tuples weight . streams)
      (if (null? streams)
          (cons-stream '() the-empty-stream)
          (let* ((stream (car streams))
                 (rest (cdr streams))
                 (rest-tuples
                   (apply stream-weighted-tuples
                          (lambda (tuple)  ; partial weight
                            (weight (cons (stream-car stream) tuple)))
                          rest)))
            (let combine-with-rest ((stream stream)
                                    (rest-tuples rest-tuples))
              (if (or (stream-null? stream)
                      (stream-null? rest-tuples))
                  the-empty-stream  ; {} x S = {}
                  (let ((s-car (stream-car stream))
                        (s-cdr (stream-cdr stream))
                        (r-car (stream-car rest-tuples))
                        (r-cdr (stream-cdr rest-tuples)))
                    (cons-stream (cons s-car r-car)
                                 (stream-merge-weighted
                                   weight
                                   (stream-map (lambda (t) (cons s-car t))
                                               r-cdr)
                                   (stream-merge-weighted
                                     weight
                                     (stream-map (lambda (x) (cons x r-car))
                                                 s-cdr)
                                     (combine-with-rest s-cdr r-cdr))))))))))
```

Note, that the `weight` procedure requires the `cdr` of tuples to be ordered independent to the `car`s, i.e., W(a, b, c) >= W(x, y, z) only if W(b, c) >= W(y, z).